# stat probability word problem

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

## 8. Suppose one of these 335,770 carloads is randomly selected. What is the probability it contains forest products or coal? [One single probability value here - P(A or B)]

## 9. Given a randomly selected carload contains either forest products or coal, what is the probability it contains coal?

so for #8 do I have to basically add coal and forest products together and divide that value by the total?

and for #10 do I have to take the coal value and divide it by the total of coal and forest?

Comment: you are right.  you have to divide the coal value by the total of coal and forest.

Answer (score 0):

Forest + Coal = 21,929 + 124,595 = 146,524

Total = 335,770 as stated

146,534 of 335,770 car loads are either Coal or Forest

1*(146,534/335,770) = 0.4364

0.4364 = 43.64%

Do the same thing for #9 except 1*(coal/(coal + forest))